# How can I render object containing dictionaries to templates in jinja2?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, templates, jinja2

suppose If lists are `a1=[ ],a2=[ ],a3=[ ],a4=[ ],a5=[ ]`

they all will have dynamic values as below:

```
a1=[]
a2=[]
a3=[{'car':'bez','city':'la','aero':'vaar'}]
a4=[]
a5=[{'car':'tez','city':'pa','aero':'vawear'}]
```

I want to render only those  which has values as in this case a3 and a5 then how can I check lists which have values then render it to template card.html

```
<table>
<tbody>
<thead>
<th>car</th>
<th>city</th>
<th>aero</th>
</thead>
{{for key in a3 /a5}}
<td>key[car]</td>
<td>key[city]</td>
<td>key[aero]</td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and   create a link to get specific object table, how can I do that?

```
<html>
<body>
<p><a hr ef="/card">card</a></p> """which gives a3 value"""
<p><a href="/card">card</a></p>"""which gives a5 value"""
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the first line your dictionaries are actually lists. Later `a3` and `a5` are invalid.

Comment: The edit did not improve it.

Comment: They are all lists (not dictionaries), two of them have a dictionary as the only item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine all the list and then iterate over it.

**Example:**

```
from jinja2 import Template

myString = """<table>
    <tbody>
        <thead>
            <th>car</th>
            <th>city</th>
            <th>aero</th>
        </thead>
        {% for key in data %}
            <td>{{ key['car'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ key['city'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ key['aero'] }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>"""

a1=[]
a2=[]
a3=[{'car':'bez','city':'la','aero':'vaar'}]
a4=[]
a5=[{'car':'tez','city':'pa','aero':'vawear'}]

d = (a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5)
data = Template(myString).render({'data': d})
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <thead>
            <th>car</th>
            <th>city</th>
            <th>aero</th>
        </thead>

            <td>bez</td>
            <td>la</td>
            <td>vaar</td>

            <td>tez</td>
            <td>pa</td>
            <td>vawear</td>

    </tbody>
</table>
```